# Is this formulation O(n) ∈ O(f) correct?

Tags: algorithm, function, time-complexity, big-o, belongs-to

Is this formulation O(n) ∈ O(ƒ) correct?

My answer is yes, because the O(n) complexity can belong to O(ƒ) if O(ƒ) > O(n) (for example if O(ƒ) = n log n).
That is to say, the complexity O(n) can be part of the set described by O(ƒ) if O(ƒ) is an upper bound of O(n).
However I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: What is f in this case? Or do you mean for an arbitrary f?

Comment: in this case f means function

Comment: This sort of theoretical question is probably better asked on [cs.se] but check their help before posting.

Answer (score 1):

"∈" means "element of", and so your formulation is not correct.

O(n) is a set of functions, and O(f) is a set of functions.  O(n) cannot be an element of O(f), because O(f) is not a set of sets.

If you want to say that "O(n) is a subset of O(f) or the same set", you write it "O(n) ⊆ O(f)".

Comment: why is O(n) a set and not just a complexity or an element from a set?

Comment: That's the way it's defined.  The definition is formal and useful.   You could define it differently, but then you wouldn't be speaking the language of computer science, and you probably wouldn't end up with a useful definition.